# PayPal Parallel vs. Adaptive functionality

Tags: paypal, magento-1.8, paypal-adaptive-payments

Definition of the proper PayPal-method on our marketplace.

It is a dental marketplace where customers can buy several products from multiple sellers (merchants) at the same time. What we need to do is a Payment that only show the different sellers on the PayPal Payment interface (incl. tax, shipping etc. on each seller/merchant) when the customer submit the order. It is important that Dentlet (our marketplace) does not figure on the customer Payment page (due to legal considerations).

Furthermore we only need to Autorize the payment during customer checkout. This is important as we don’t want the customer to transfer the payment to seller/merchant before the actual item is shipped/invoiced (or part of the items are shipped/invoiced).Capture should be on Invoice generated by our marketplace based on shipment. Instantly when/after the Payment has been captured, then we need to do a commission from the seller/merchant PayPal account to Dentlet PayPal account.

Earlier on we have been suggested to go with Express Checkout in this scenario, but due to some challenges implementing we have now been advised to go with: pre-approval with adaptive chained payment. Somehow it seems like we need some functionality from both Parallel and Adaptive -  we dont know how to make this happen.

All architectural advises will be appreciated and a freelance consultancy job is available as well.

Best Regards,
Mikael

Comment: I would indeed recommend Express Checkout for this over Adaptive Payments.  What challenges did you have with it?

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for getting back to me. We did go with Express Checkout and Parallel, but we did have an issue getting it to work with the part of doing a second payment from the seller to the website automatically. I can see that you have extensive experience in PayPal would I be able to hire you in to trouble shoot our solution :)?

Comment: I received your email.  I will get back to you there soon.